# Cannot schedule task to run under domain user account other than current user

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

On our Win 2008 machines I can't schedule tasks for domain users because the domain name does not resolve to network name but the AD dc name.

The "network name" looks like **ABCDEFGE-HIJKLM** and the "dc" / "name" would look like **ABCDEFGE-HIJKLMN**.

When selecting the domain user account the account qualifier will look like **ABCDEFGE-HIJKLMN\task.user**. This results in an "invalid account" error.

Entering the account name as **task.user@ABCDEFGE-HIJKLMN.org** yields the same result.

When however keeping the currently logged in user it will display **ABCDEFGE-HIJKLM\current.user**.

Does this behaviour result from the presumable "illegal" domain name?

Is there a workaround for this?

**update**

I could of course log in as the desired domain account and create the task but since this account is a account used for running services I want to avoid creating a user profile on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just worked for me:

Select a local account

When clicking "ok" you get a prompt for the password
There you can change the user to the correct user eg. COMPANYNAME\username

source:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverManagement/thread/3d9e45be-0225-46f3-b1b6-504915896605

Comment: Exporting, editing and importing worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for the hint to this workaround.

Comment: I'll upvote as soon as my rep here allows.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the task.user@ABCDEFGE-HIJKLMN.local format? (I am assuming that your domain is setup as ABCDEFGE-HIJKLMN.local in DNS.)

Comment: I tried that and it also resolves the account to ABCDEFGE-HIJKLMN\task.user resulting in the same error. Thanks for your suggestion nonetheless.